# Git / Maven: How to work with customized projects that have a common parent project

Tags: git, maven, project-management

In my company we work with customized projects that are based on a single basic solution. The customized solutions are Maven projects that have as parent the basic solution, which is another Maven project. All, each of the customized projects and the basic solution, are different Git projects.

To give you a better idea, the basic solution (project CORE in Git) may define the basic life cycle of an alarm and then it is up to each customized project (let' say projects NYC and NJ in Git) to implement the code that handles particular use cases for this alarm.

As you see I have three projects CORE, NYC and NJ. The last two depending on the first.

Our problem is that while developing for NYC or NJ we may find bugs or changes that apply for CORE. Because of this, part of the developers think that our development of NYC and NJ should be based always in the last SNAPSHOT version of CORE and if we have to release NYC, we release first the CORE to a fix version, we release then NYC pointing to this fix version of CORE, and then we point the development version of NYC and NJ to the new snapshot of CORE. However, other developers, we think that this is not correct and the development of NYC or NJ should be based in concrete versions of CORE. If you have to release NYC, you make a branch of the fix version of CORE and if later you have to make an adjustment on CORE for this release of NYC, you do it in this branch you created at the release time. Otherwise, if we are based always in the latest SNAPSHOT, when you have to develop a new feature for one of the customized projects time later after you made a release, you are not sure what is included in the latest version of CORE and even your solution project may have compilation problems.

As you see we are having a big discussion between the supporters of working with our customized projects pointing to SNAPSHOT versions of CORE or fixed ones.

I am sure there must be a standard work flow for this kind of architecture but after making some research I couldn't find much about it. I would be grateful if you could share how do you work with similar projects, the pros and cons, or if you could point me to some white paper or book describing a standardized way to manage such mess.

Answer (score 0):

I know this discussion very well, with the opinion "the latest version is always the right version to use" and the opposing opinion "take a stable version and update it regularly by hand".

I think we should distinguish two situations:

1. Regular development
2. Fixing bugs in already released versions.

Let me discuss the second point first: When you fix a bug, you should start from the released version (not from the code your working on at the moment), both for your core and your customised projects. You have probably tagged the releases in Git, so you can checkout your core and your project and construct bugfix versions.

In the regular development, you have two choices:

1. Using the SNAPSHOT version of the core which means that you have zero manual update work, but you always risk to break your projects by unexpected changes in core.
2. Regularly making manual updates to the latest release version is more work, but ensures that you exactly know when to be careful (and all other times, you know what you get). This is more like you would handle external dependencies (log4j, apache commons, ...).

Comment: "When you fix a bug, you should start from the released version". Looks promising but I still don't quite see the whole work flow. So once you have fixed your bug on the core branch that was tagged after the released version, at some point you will still need to merge this branch into the development one. When would you do so? Immediately or when make a new release of the core?

Comment: If a fix of an old bug is still relevant for the recent code, integrate the bug fix as soon as possible (either immediately, or directly after the next release) in the development branch.